# HTTP Error 500.19 - IIS 7.5, ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm trying to get my MVC 4 web application deployed to IIS 7.5 but I'm running into a Internal Server error I cannot work around.

It seems to be choking on the bindingRedirect.  Taking it out causes other errors and so it is certainly needed.  I've got this installed on another IIS server and my local IIS with the same web.config and it works just fine.

```
    HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

    The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

    Module    IIS Web Core 

    Notification    Unknown 

    Handler    Not yet determined 

    Error Code    0x8007000d 

    Config Error    Configuration file is not well-formed XML  

    Config File    \\?\D:\Reporting\web.config 

    Requested URL    http://localhost:80/ 

    Physical Path

    Logon Method    Not yet determined 

    Logon User    Not yet determined

Config Source    

<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion=""0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Here is my web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <section name="syscache2" type="NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheSection, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2" />

  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.TraceLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
        <arg key="level" value="DEBUG" />
        <arg key="showLogName" value="false" />
        <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
        <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <syscache2>
    <!--See Configuration At: http://bit.ly/Yf12K1-->
    <cacheRegion name="hourly" relativeExpiration="3600" priority="Low" />
  </syscache2>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="MvcPaging" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion=""0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" />
        <bindingRedirect newVersion="3.3.1.4000" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Windsor" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Does your apppool have access to the directory where the web.config is stored?

Comment: Yes.  I setup a new local user with local admin rights and used that for the identity of my apppool.  I gave that user full rights to the web site's folder and replaced all child object permissions so it would cover all subfolders and files.